# hidden files taking far too much space [SOLVED]

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, disk-usage, hidden-files

In order to instal ubuntu 14.04 I backed up my hard drive (650 Gb). In the new installation I partitioned the hard drive giving 1.8 Tb to ubuntu 14.04 and leaving 100 Gb for Biolinux 8. Now I am copying back my hard drive to the 1.8 Tb part and I run out of space and I realised it is full of hidden files and directories such as .perlbrew .remmina .icedtea .pulse .nx .StrapAlign and a long etc. what do I do with them?

How can I make space?

Thanks

Adding df -h:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       1.7T  1.6T     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G  236K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4        95G   11G   80G  12% /media/sol/face7453-c17c-48f7-b6b0-ed1aac201cc4`

$ du -hs hhd/*
916K    hhd/allpairwise.txt
3.1G    hhd/anaconda_ete
61M hhd/b2gFiles
5.4G    hhd/cgat-install
616M    hhd/CytoscapeConfiguration
4.0K    hhd/DEseq2.R
6.5M    hhd/Desktop
612G    hhd/Documents
1.8G    hhd/Downloads
 12K    hhd/examples.desktop
380K    hhd/fontconfig
4.0K    hhd/GENE-E
 50M    hhd/IGB
4.9M    hhd/igv
1.1M    hhd/logs
1.4M    hhd/MAplot_correctedpvalues.tiff
   0    hhd/Music
636K    hhd/output.fa
3.4M    hhd/pairwise_1.txt
3.4M    hhd/pairwise_2.txt
520M    hhd/perl5
   0    hhd/Pictures
 16K    hhd/print2.pdf
 56K    hhd/print.pdf
1.4M    hhd/pvalues_1_corrected.tiff
1.4M    hhd/pvalues_1.tiff
660K    hhd/setuptools-18.6.1.zip
137M    hhd/Tablet
   0    hhd/Videos
128K    hhd/test.txt
4.0K    hhd/test2.txt
 68K    hhd/real.txt
128K    hhd/real2.txt
4.0K    hhd/extended.txt
 68K    hhd/extended2.txt
160K    hhd/reduced.txt
4.0K    hhd/reduced2.txt
160K    hhd/outliers.txt`

$ du -hs hhd/
1.6T    hhd/`
```

Comment: could you post us your `df -h` so we can see your actual partitioning.

Comment: Why do you think it is the hidden files that take up so much space? Hidden files tend to be used by applications to store user-dependent configuration items, not as bulk storage.

Comment: Well your sda2 is completely full, maybe you wanna try searching what is actually taking up so much space? `du -sh /*` would list all directories/files in / and summarize them in their capacity.

Comment: If I do right click over the folder and then properties I see 663.4 GB, if I do $du -hs on the terminal it shows 1.7 Tb I though the difference between the two would be accounting for hidden files

Comment: @Ziazis if I do `du -hs /*` I see that Documents folder is 613G which is the size I know it has, the rest of things are K or M, I don't see where the remaining 900 Gb are coming from

Comment: Can you post the whole output of the command? You might need to use sudo since you're trying to also read only root directories etc.

Comment: edited post @Ziazis

Comment: something doesn't add up, did you also try du -ha /hhd/* ? Because these are hidden files/all files. Btw. how did you backup the files/restore them?

Comment: I just checked du -sh hhd/.* and it gives 3.1G so no, it doesn't add up at all. I copied the hhd folder to the server (cloud) and now I am copying it back down. I just checked the size of the folder in the cloud and it is 2,4T which doesn't make sense that it was that size on the first place because I don't have such much space in my hard drive... I am not sure what to do, maybe I just copy the most important folder Documents alone and then I check one by one the rest of the files. But I am intrigued with those 900 Gb that don't show up anywhere

Comment: oh they might be just normal files, with -s you do tell du to only summarize the folders. try `du -ha --except Documents Desktop blabla blabla ./` and you will get a listing of all files in your hhd folder edit: also yes - it seems something went wrong in your backup then?

Answer (score 2):

`Baobab` is useful - gives you a nice ring chart showing what's taking up your space, 1/2 a 1.8T drive should be pretty obvious! It isn't installed by default - it's Gnome so you may find it comes with clutter, and you'd need to install it - so perhaps use a USB drive to do this?

Once you've located the rogue file(s), then deleting becomes trivial - but it is unusual for a hidden file to get too big, perhaps a log file, so you may want to come back with the name(s) later in case something needs stopping.

Answer (score 0):

found it!
Using

```
$ du -hs ulg/.* 
971G    ulg/.wine
```